# How to make constructor called after autowired?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I am initializing a load cache in the constructor which needs autowired parameters. But due to spring bean sequence, I can' t get it right. So userLdapGroupsCache is created without setting timeout and size. Do you guys have any suggestion to fix this? Thanks.

```java
  private LoadingCache<String, Set<String>> userLdapGroupsCache;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("cacheExpireTime")
  private int cacheExpireTime;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("cacheMaxSize")
  private int cacheMaxSize;

 public LdapAuthorization ()
  {
    userLdapGroupsCache = 
    CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
     .maximumSize(cacheMaxSize)
     .expireAfterWrite(cacheExpireTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
     .build(new CacheLoader<String, Set<String>>() {
              @Override
              public Set<String> load(String key) throws Exception {
                return getGroups(key);
              }
            });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the initialization of that object inside a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`:

```
  @PostConstruct
  public void init()
  {
    userLdapGroupsCache = 
    CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
     .maximumSize(cacheMaxSize)
     .expireAfterWrite(cacheExpireTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
     ...
  }
```

Thanks to that it will be initialized with injected parameters as methods annotated with `@PostConstruct` are invoked after all of the fields have been injected into the bean.

Comment: The downside of this way, vs constructor injection, is that userLdapGroupsCache is not final

Answer (score 1):

It seems that field injection is starting to be frowned upon. You might want to use constructor injection. The upside to this as opposed to the `@PostConstruct` way is that your cache is final.

```
private final LoadingCache<String, Set<String>> userLdapGroupsCache;

public LdapAuthorization (
  @Qualifier("cacheExpireTime") int cacheExpireTime,
  @Qualifier("cacheMaxSize") int cacheMaxSize
) {
  userLdapGroupsCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
     .maximumSize(cacheMaxSize)
     .expireAfterWrite(cacheExpireTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pass `cacheExpireTime` and `cacheMaxSize` into constructor and make those private fields final. You will find multiple goals achieved from this behaviour.

P.S. Looks like you can use lambda here:

```java
...
.build(new CacheLoader<String, Set<String>>() {
    @Override
    public Set<String> load(String key) throws Exception {
        return getGroups(key);
    }
});
```

Comment: If they are only needed to initialize the cache then you don't need them as fields and your class gets a little cleaner.

Comment: Application specific. Or more accurate - bean specific. Usually you would have singleton there so constructor should be enough, giving the example in the question